# React App - trying to control dynamically-created material-ui TextInput's but not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am getting "TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined" whenever I type anything in the input field. Here is the code which the error refers me to in the parent component:

```
handleCertificationChange = (index, e) => {
   let certifications = [...this.state.certifications];
   certifications[index] = {...certifications[index], [e.target.name]: e.target.value};
   this.setState({ certifications });
}
```

My initial state:

```
this.state = {
   certifications: [{ certification: '' }]
}
```

Here is how I call TextField in the child component:

```
renderCertificationFields = () => {
        const { certifications } = this.props.values;
        const { handleCertificationChange } = this.props; //receiving as props from parent component

        return certifications.map((item, index) => (
            <Grid container spacing={1} key={index}>    
                <Grid item md={10}>
                    <TextField
                        label='Certification name'
                        name='certification'
                        onChange={(index, event) => handleCertificationChange(index, event)}
                        defaultValue={item.certification || ''}
                    />
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        ))
    }
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the JSX, the `event` object is the first and only parameter in the `onChange` callback - so you don't need to define `index` in the callback, only to your own method.

```
onChange={(event) => handleCertificationChange(index, event)}
```